# Can i grab Click and DoubleClick in a node treeview C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to define different handlers for click and double click events in a node in a TreeView, but the click event is always fired and the double ignored.
Can I have both working?

**try 1**

```
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text.ToUpper());
    }
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text);
    }
```

**try2**

```
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Clicks)
        {
            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text); break;
            case 2:
                MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text.ToUpper()); break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would strongly caution you against causing some action to occur when a node is double-clicked. That is a common way of expanding/collapsing a node, and if you start hooking up additional behavior, you run the risk of confusing users.

Comment: Also, it would be better if you could post the code for your `TreeView`'s `Click` and `DoubleClick` event handlers... The issue must lie somewhere there (perhaps you're canceling the click event or showing a message box?) because the `DoubleClick` event works perfectly fine for me in an empty test app.

Comment: hi Cody, i added the code to the question

Comment: @Cody Gray it's perfectly fine to have an action on double click if the node has no children

Comment: @voodoomsr, really this is your code? how do you want have double click within message boxes?

Comment: @Saeed I use mboxes only to show the point of the question, if you change them for example for Trace.Writeline the same problem arise, and that has nothing to do with modal dialogs

Comment: @voodoomsr both Click and DoubleClick will fire, I guess you are doing something wrong, try Debug.WriteLine as suggested by Cody. Also you should accept Cody's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this method... but this is not a proper way

need a timer control, say timer1, set interval 500.

```
timer1.Interval = 500;
```

declare a variable to check mouse click

```
static int mClick = 0;
```

in the treeview mouse down

```
private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mClick++;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

in the timer tick

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            if (mClick == 1)
            {
                mClick = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("single click");

            }
            if (mClick == 2)
            {
                mClick = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("double click");
            }

        }
```

this is working properly in my side.

rest is up to you...

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, you *always* get the Click event first when the user double-clicks.  Knowing that she intended to double-click requires a time machine.  You can create one, start a Timer in the Click event and set its Interval to SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime + 45.

When you get the DoubleClick event set the timer's Enable property to false and do the double-click action.  When you get the Tick event, set the timer's Enable property to false and do the single-click action.  It doesn't make for a great user interface experience.

You didn't get the DoubleClick event because of the message box, it jerks the focus away.

Answer (score 2):

As I suspected, the problem is that you're showing a `MessageBox` on the `Click` event. **When that message box gets displayed, it "hogs" all input (message boxes are modal dialogs) and the user's second click on the `TreeView` doesn't get recognized.**

[Hans Passant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527133/can-i-grab-click-and-doubleclick-in-a-node-treeview-c/4527209#4527209) already provides a detailed explanation of how Windows determines if a click event is a `Click` or `DoubleClick`, so I won't rehash that here.

However, the solution is simple: **Remove the `MessageBox.Show` statements from your event handlers and everything will work as expected.** You'll need to find some other way to alert the user to the node that was selected (if that's even necessary), but that will turn out to be a blessing in disguise. A message box popping up every time a node is clicked on is not exactly a friendly UI. For your particular scenario (at least as best I can tell), there's no need for more complicated techniques like a timer.

This also presents an important larger lesson in debugging code involving Windows user interface elements. Any time you throw a `MessageBox` into the mix, you run the risk of breaking the delicate sequence of events. The best drop-in replacement is probably a call to [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) instead.

Comment: hehehe, the messagebox i put in was only for testing purpose, it doesn't have anything to do in my application, the real actions that i want to put are for single click: preview the content of the underling data they represent in a preview texbox that i have somewhere else, and for doble click, copy the node to the root of the tree. I repeat the mbox was only used for to see if it is possible to have both behavior at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check number of clicks in Click event handler. It should be in EventArgs instance.

Comment: i try but it always get fired first the action for 1 click

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the click handler from the code above then the double click handler should fire. Because the click handler shows a dialog, there is no way for the second click of the double click to reach the double click handler.